# Creating a Microsoft Graph webhook subscription to security/alerts fails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

When I attempt to create a Microsoft Graph webhook subscription to the security/alerts endpoint, the subscription creation fails with a generic message as shown below. Modifying the resource to 'me/messages' results in a successful webhook subscription created, so this appears to be specific to the security/alerts endpoint. How do I move past this?

[image]

The body of the request is as such:

```
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/graphnotifications",
  "resource": "security/alerts?$filter=vendorInformation/provider+eq+'ASC'",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-11-15T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}
```

Comment: Wes, can you share the actual request url you are using here too? just to be double sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 'updated' for 'changeType'. Security/Alerts uses 'updated' for all new or updated alerts.

Comment: Perfect, this solved the issue. Suggest adding more descriptive feedback in the 400 and maybe updating the docs to not include "created" in the sample changeType.

Answer (score 0):

Wes, you didn't post the URL that you sent that request to. As per the documentation for Security Alerts.

> You can use Microsoft Graph webhooks to subscribe to and receive notifications about updates to Microsoft Graph Security entities.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/security-api-overview

On that page, it states posting a request and gives a sample like this

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/notificationClient",
  "resource": "/me/mailfolders('inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2016-03-20T11:00:00.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/webhooks

Are you posting that request body to that url?